# Apache LoadBalancing: SSL/TLS settings for healthchecks

Tags: apache, load-balancing, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

I'm trying to setup a loadbalancer with apache. The communication to the backend servers is TLS-encrypted. When i enable healthchecks, this works as long as the ProxySSL* directives are set on VHost Level, and not inside the Proxy section.
When i move them inside the Proxy section, the SSL/TLS settings are no longer evaluated correctly (the connection to the backend uses the default SSL/TLS settings and not the one specified). But according to [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyprotocol), it should be possible to define SSL/TSL settings inside a Proxy section, which should allow to set *different SSL/TLS settings for different LoadBalancers*.

What works:

```
  <VHost ...>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass "/"  "balancer://mybalancer"
    SSLProxyProtocol [a protocol]
    SSLProxyCipherSuite  [a cipher suite]
    <Proxy balancer://mybalancer>
      BalancerMember https://www.backend1.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck1.php
      BalancerMember https://www.backend2.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck2.php
   </Proxy>
  </VHost>
```

In the above example, healthchecks, as well as ordinary requests use the Protocol and CipherSuite specified. The problem with this solution is, that i cannot create a second balancer inside the same VHost with different SSL/TLS settings. Unfortunately thats exactly what i need.

What does not work:

```
<VHost ...>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass "/"  "balancer://mybalancer"
    ProxyPass "/2"  "balancer://mybalancer2"
    <Proxy balancer://mybalancer>
      SSLProxyProtocol [a protocol]
      SSLProxyCipherSuite  [a cipher suite]
      BalancerMember https://www.backend1.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck1.php
      BalancerMember https://www.backend2.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck2.php
   </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://mybalancer2>
      SSLProxyProtocol [another protocol]
      SSLProxyCipherSuite  [another cipher suite]
      BalancerMember https://www.backend3.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck1.php
      BalancerMember https://www.backend4.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck2.php
   </Proxy>
</VHost>
```

Like this, Protocol and CipherSuite specified have no effect on healthchecks, instead, healthchecks for both balancers use the default settings specified in the global scope of httpd.conf.

I think setting SSLProtocol and SSLCipherSuite for healthchecks is a quite common case, and i'm wondering if someone has a setup that works, or if someone has faced the same problems.

Thanks in advance for any help or hints where to look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to yann and armin for help on this. it works with the patch provided in this bug-report:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62556#c6

(you only need [attachment 36043](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=36043), the other patch is wrong/not needed!)

as discussed there, the problem is that the worker for the balancer member is not correctly initialized.
this is why we have to set **at least one proxy parameter**.

If we extend the above Proxy balancer:// definition like below, it works:(after the patch, of course):

```
<Proxy balancer://mybalancer2 lbmethod=byrequests>
```

We can take any of the lb-parameters here, and we can easily set it to the default value. (lbmethod=byrequests is default, so nothing is changed except the worker is correctly initialized).

the complete, working example from above:

```
<VHost ...>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass "/"  "balancer://mybalancer"
    ProxyPass "/2"  "balancer://mybalancer2"
    <Proxy balancer://mybalancer lbmethod=byrequests>
      SSLProxyProtocol [a protocol]
      SSLProxyCipherSuite  [a cipher suite]
      BalancerMember https://www.backend1.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck1.php
      BalancerMember https://www.backend2.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck2.php
   </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://mybalancer2 lbmethod=byrequests>
      SSLProxyProtocol [another protocol]
      SSLProxyCipherSuite  [another cipher suite]
      BalancerMember https://www.backend3.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck1.php
      BalancerMember https://www.backend4.com hcinterval=1 hcmethod=get hcuri=/healthcheck2.php
   </Proxy>
</VHost>
```

the patch should be included in the next release, maybe probably 2.4.35